# Select menu in bash

Tags: bash, menu, formatting

For some reason, my menu renders like this:

```
1) RUNTHROUGH         6) option 4
2) QUIT               7) option leg
3) NEW SEARCH PATERN    8) option arm
4) CLEAR SEARCHES             9) option whatever
5) option 1                          10) option blabla
```

,but I would like it to be aligned properly, like this:

```
1) RUNTHROUGH         6) option 4
2) QUIT               7) option leg
3) NEW SEARCH PATERN  8) option arm
4) CLEAR SEARCHES     9) option whatever
5) option 1          10) option blabla
```

How can I do that?

I am populating menu from two arrays:

One is constructed from label variables like this:

```
MENU_OPTIONS=( "$SCRIPT_RUNTHROUGH" "$PROGRAM_QUIT" "$PATTERN_NEW" "$PATTERN_CLEAR" )
```

where variable has value like this, with color escapes

```
SCRIPT_RUNTHROUGH=$'\e[1;31mRUNTHROUGH\e[0;33m'
PROGRAM_QUIT=$'\e[1;31mQUIT\e[0;33m'
PATTERN_NEW=$'\e[1;31mNEW SEARCH PATERN\e[0;33m'
PATTERN_CLEAR=$'\e[1;31mCLEAR SEARCHES\e[0;33m'
```

and another array `entries` is coming from file:

```
readarray -t entries < ./file
```

content of `file` is raw text data:

```
option 1
option 4
option leg
option arm
option whatever
option blabla
```

so `select` block goes like:

```
select opt in "${MENU_OPTIONS[@]}" "${entries[@]}";
do
    case "$opt" in
        ...)
        ;;
```

Comment: can you show the code that causes this?

Comment: @andrew see my addition please.

Comment: @branquito Can you show all the variables, the file, and have your example output match what is actually printed? As written, you haven't really provided a minimal example of the error.

Comment: @BroSlow now you have real output example..

Answer (score 3):

Bash mostly count the char in each option, regardless they are "displayable" or not. So, the escape code used to highlight some of your items false the display.

Here is an example:

```
sh$ for i in {1..12}; do OPTIONS[$i]=$(printf "option-%02d" $i); done
sh$ select i in "${OPTIONS[@]}"; do echo $i ; done
1) option-01    4) option-04   7) option-07  10) option-10
2) option-02    5) option-05   8) option-08  11) option-11
3) option-03    6) option-06   9) option-09  12) option-12
```

This is as expected. But if I highlight the 4th item:

```
sh$ OPTIONS[4]=$'\e[1;31moption-04\e[0;33m'
sh$ select i in "${OPTIONS[@]}"; do echo $i ; done
1) option-01    4) option-04           7) option-07  10) option-10
2) option-02    5) option-05   8) option-08  11) option-11
3) option-03    6) option-06   9) option-09  12) option-12
```

---

**WORKAROUND**

Well ... it's more a hack than a workaround. Really.

I add some extra spaces at the end of every option in order to widen the columns. Instead, I add a few `\b` at the end of the highlighted option (6 gave good results on my tests). I can't be more precise, since I wasn't able to clearly determine the rule to follow. You probably have to be prepared for trial and error...
<sub>(thing are even more complicated by the fact `Bash` uses a mix of *tab* and *space* to indent the various options)</sub>

Anyway, this display properly on *my* system:

```
sh$ for i in {1..12}; do OPTIONS[$i]=$(printf "option-%02d        " $i); done
#                                                         ^^^^^^^^
sh$ OPTIONS[4]=$'\e[1;31moption-04\e[0;33m\b\b\b\b\b\b'
#                                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^
sh$ select i in "${OPTIONS[@]}"; do echo $i ; done
1) option-01            5) option-05           9) option-09        
2) option-02            6) option-06          10) option-10        
3) option-03            7) option-07          11) option-11        
4) option-04            8) option-08          12) option-12
```

---

**EDIT**: I was puzzled by the fact in my example, the menu was off by 8 char. Doesn't match with the number of *bytes* in the various escape codes.

But, given the code from GNU bash 4.2 :
(`execute_cmd.c`)

```
static int
displen (s)
     const char *s;
{
#if defined (HANDLE_MULTIBYTE)
  wchar_t *wcstr;
  size_t wclen, slen;

  wcstr = 0;
  slen = mbstowcs (wcstr, s, 0);
  if (slen == -1)
    slen = 0;
  wcstr = (wchar_t *)xmalloc (sizeof (wchar_t) * (slen + 1));
  mbstowcs (wcstr, s, slen + 1);
  wclen = wcswidth (wcstr, slen);
  free (wcstr);
  return ((int)wclen);
#else
  return (STRLEN (s));
#endif
}
```

It appears that if Bash is compiled with multibyte support, it converts the raw string using `mbstowcs` in order to calculate its length using `wcswidth`. Given my system has UTF-8 LC_CTYPE, probably `mbstowcs` misconverted the escape code as some Unicode character...

Comment: Any chance of avoiding that offset? I remember once, I saw something like additional escaping with `\[`, so that formatting is left alone?

Comment: I tried to escape the _other_ options, adding `\e[0;33` both as prefix and suffix, in order to have the same error in all items. I thought I was clever. Alas. The problem is, as calculation are wrong, each menu line is too long, and wrap to the other line... As of "magical escaping", the Bash source code give little hope in that domain (see my _EDIT_)...

Comment: How is that, when I use your example it renders in one column, all options, and you have it in 4, each column 3 items?

Comment: @branquito The layout algorithm is quite unpredictable. I am on 80 column terminal. Are you? Anyway, good news: I have a workaround. Not necessary very robust but... Give me few minutes to edit my answer again. Oups false hope: it doesn't work...

Comment: I tried this, but it seems that it does not give expected results: http://serverfault.com/questions/93878/bash-custom-prompt-breaking-wrapping-of-long-command-lines

Comment: @branquito `\[` and `\]` are prompt-specific special characters (see `man bash` -- section PROMPTING).